# Xcode building into project dir?

Tags: xcode

I have an app that's building into my project directory, rather than into DerviedData. In Preferences, Build Locations I have Derived Data set to Default. My other projects are all building as expected.

How do I fix this?

I have not set `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`, `CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR`, `OBJROOT`, `SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR` or `SYMROOT` in project or target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under **File** choose **Project Settings**. This command seems to be misnamed; you're actually editing the workspace settings. Make sure **Derived Data Location** is set to **Default**.

This will apply even if your project doesn't have a workspace, as each project has an embedded workspace.